# App crashes when tapping the back button, immediately after tapping "Favourite"

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

If you follow a link to a question (within another question), then tap Favourite (on the linked question) and then try to go back to the previous question immediately via the Android system back button, the app crashes. This causes a crash every time.

This is on a Nexus 5 running Android 5.1.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed in 1.0.83.

The app was trying to shout "Post favorited" into the eternal abyss of `null` and the abyss pushed back.